# SQL, count both open and closed sessions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, aggregate-functions

Given this table:

```
  Session | User | Start      | Stop  
        1 |    1 | 2014-10-10 | null  
        2 |    1 | 2014-10-10 | 2014-10-10  
        3 |    1 | 2014-09-10 | 2014-09-10  
        4 |    2 | 2014-10-10 | null  
        5 |    2 | 2014-10-10 | 2014-10-10
```

I want to count how many open sessions each user has, AND the total number of sessions for that user for a given date:

```
 User | Date       | Open | Total |
    1 | 2014-10-10 |    1 |     2 |
    1 | 2014-09-10 |    0 |     1 |
    2 | 2014-10-10 |    1 |     2 |
```

By grouping on both user, start and stop, I'm able to get two rows, one with open sessions and one with closed, but I would rather have two columns...

(I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2)

Comment: Is it a valid case for a session to span more than one day?  That would complicate things a bit, right?

Comment: Nah. The whole point of this is to show some basic statistics on how many current vs total users there are. So if a session is started one day, and closed the next, the stats will count it the day it started. If it started yesterday, and it's still open, I will count it as part of yesterdays total.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a case expression to count conditionally:

```
select
  user,
  start as [date],
  count(case when stop is null then 1 end) as open,
  count(*) as total
from sessions
group by user, start;
```

Comment: ISNULL(sum(case when stop is null then 1 end), 0) AS open, because SUM for NULL == NULL, and if we not have a columns with stop IS NULL, it return NULL

Comment: @realnumber3012: Yes, I had just noticed that. So I use COUNT now. You are right, with SUM one would have to use COALESCE or the like to make the null a zero.

Comment: Great! One more thing: I have timestamps that I convert into dates with `cast(start as Date)`. Is there a way of defining that once, so that I can refer to that value later without doing a new cast? Like in `where date = '2014-09-10'`?

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is a derived table, i.e. select the date in a sub query: `select mydate from (select cast(start as date) as mydate from mytable) where mydate = '2014-09-10'`.

Comment: For future reference, this is what I ended up with:
`
  select
   user,
  cast(s.start as Date) as date,
  count(case when (s.stopp is null) and (s.Start >= cast(GETDATE() as Date)) then 1 end) as [open],
  count(*) as total
 from sessions as s
 group by s.user, cast(s.start as Date)
 order by date`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.user, t.start, 
sum(
case
   when stop is null then 1 else 0
end) as 'Open',
count(t.start) as 'Total'
FROM yourtable t
GROUP BY t.user, t.start
```